# checking for nested object property existence (and assigning to nonexistent nested property)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

(Nested property exists flex yielded nothing relevant in google).

How do you check for the existance of obj.x.y.z - is a try catch block the only option?

I came up with the following - it didn't work:

```
    private function exists(obj:Object, ... args):Boolean {

      for (var n:int=0; n<args.length; n++) {
        if (obj[args[n]] == undefined)
          return false;
        if (n<(length-1))
          obj = obj[args[n]];
      }

      return true;  

    }
```

A second part to this would be assigning to obj.x.y.z before you know if obj.x or obj.x.y exists.  I came up with the following which *does* work, but don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Is there already a standard way of doing this:

```
private function set(obj_set:Object, obj:Object, ...args):void {

  for (var n:int=0; n<args.length; n++) {
    if (n < args.length-1) { 
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(args[n]))                          
        obj[args[n]] = new Object();
      obj = obj[args[n]];
      continue;
    }
    obj[args[n]] = obj_set;

  }

}
```

Comment: try replacing `if (obj[args[n]] == undefined)` with `if(!obj[args[n]])
`

Comment: OK, but also I said length instead of args.length in that first one -  that was the primary problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a standard way of doing this in AS3. You will need a custom helper like this to do it.